# Is there a way to restart a launchd service if it stops responding on a port?

Tags: launchd, monitoring, http

I have a service configured via `launchd` to automatically restart when it crashes. Unfortunately it will sometimes hang, and stop working, without actually crashing. I can detect when this has happens because it stops responding to HTTP on a specific port.

What's the best way to automatically restart the service when this happens?

I've thought about creating a separate launchd agent whose only purpose is to periodically poll the HTTP port and `kill` the service when it stops responding. But I feel like there must be a better way to do it, perhaps built into `launchd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Heartbeat / Healthcheck

The act of polling a URL to monitor a service is often referred to as checking for a **heartbeat**. Popular tools like `docker` promote this polling approach, see `docker`'s [`healthcheck`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) configuration entry for an example:

> The HEALTHCHECK instruction tells Docker how to test a container to check that it's still working. This can detect cases such as a web server stuck in an infinite loop and unable to handle new connections, even though the server process is still running.

You could [replicate this approach](https://blog.nfld.me/setting-up-a-heartbeat-script-for-docker-images) with a `cronjob` and shell script to restart your HTTP service. See [health check of web page using curl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84814) for a related question.

Answer (score 1):

`launchd` can’t detect if a launched process gets stuck, so you need to handle this yourself:

- Debug/fix the code to avoid the hangs,
- Redesign the daemon to detect the situation itself (e.g. by having `launchd` start a wrapper which both starts the actual daemon and periodically checks for hangs,
- Have a separate job to periodically check for hangs.